# Extract a substring in a NetSuite saved search

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I have the following: Auto Parts : Manufacturers : Mercedes Benz
I need to extract the brand Mercedes Benz from this in a saved search inside NetSuite.

Comment: On what field/column is that coming from?

Comment: can you please explain more what are you doing ? 
what is the record type, field type, from where this value is come from ? 
you question is ambiguous and not clear. Please post some code to see where you get this value from

Comment: Apologies. It is a custom column in a custom record. It is a string field and I need to use it through a saved search without scripting. I need it exposed in the search using a formula. Thank you for your feedback. I got the answer I needed from Nathan Sutherland (below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

formulatext: TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR({yourfieldid}, '[^:]+$'))

Comment: Perfect. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to make the save search(according to the requirement).

```
var SaveSearch = nlapiSearchRecord("customer", null,
                [
                    ["email", "is", 'xyz@email.com']
                ],
                [
                    new nlobjSearchColumn("firstname"),
                    new nlobjSearchColumn("lastname"),
                    new nlobjSearchColumn("email")
                ]);

if (SaveSearch) {
                var data = getAllResults(SaveSearch, SaveSearch[0].getAllColumns());
            }
```

In the above snippet, we make the save search and then check that if there something in the save search then it goes into the loop and calls the function that is `getAllResults`.

```
// calling the function
function getAllResults(SaveSearch, col) {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < leadSearch.length; i++) {

        array.push({
            'firstname': leadSearch[i].getValue(col[0]),
            'lastname': leadSearch[i].getValue(col[1]),
            'email': leadSearch[i].getValue(col[2])
        })
    }

    return array;
}
```

In this, we push the save search field into the array and make sure that is according to the column that we created while making save search otherwise value may be assigned to some other key.

Hope this helps.